# List<T> get random element doesn't work

Tags: c#

I have the following piece of code:

```
    private Random r = new Random();

    private List<T> RandomElement<T>(IQueryable<T> list, Expression<Func<T, bool>> e, int items = 3)
    {
        list = list.Where(e);
        return list.Skip(r.Next(list.Count())).Take(items).ToList();
    }
```

The problem is when I call it and want for example to return 3 random items from a list, sometimes returns 3 sometimes 2, sometimes 1 ?

I want at all time to get 3.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: As the name suggests, *Skip* skips n elements which means it may skip all elements in your list :) Have you read about `fisher yates shuffle`? If not, Google it and read the first result.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually never heard of it but I will give it a read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 10 elements in your list, and you ask for 3 "random" items, in your solution if the random number generator returns 8, you skip the first 8 elements and it only has 2 items available to return (items 9 and 10). That is why it is happening.

If you want random items, instead shuffle the list and do not skip any, just take the number you want.

[Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp)

Comment: `If you want random items, instead shuffle the list`, Funny that accepted answer uses *fisher yates shuffle* in your link